# Conditional appending to an array

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary

**I load data from Firebase into my custom "CommentModel" (newComment):**

```
// Load the comment with id
func observeComment(commentId: String, completion: @escaping (CommentModel) -> Void) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("comments").document(commentId).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
        guard let dic = snapshot?.data() else { return }
        let newComment = CommentModel(dictionary: dic)

        completion(newComment)
    }
}
```

**My Model:**

```
import UIKit

class CommentModel {

var postId: String?
var userUid: String?
var postText: String?
var postDate: Double?

init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    postId = dictionary["postId"] as? String
    userUid = dictionary["userUid"] as? String
    postText = dictionary["postText"] as? String
    postDate = dictionary["postDate"] as? Double
    }
}
```

Which gives me the following result:

```
["user2" : 5], ["user1" : 4], ["user2" : 3], ["user1" : 2], ["user1" : 1]
```

What I am trying to achieve: Call a function in "observeComments" and append the data if the userID does not already exists and if the number is the lower than the existing number and load it into a new "CommentModel", no matter how much comments or user I have.

The result should look like:

```
["user1" : 2], ["user1" : 1]
```

Because I have two userIDs and returning the lowest number.

Comment: Reading the question again it is not clear to me if `postMapping` will contain all elements and you want to filter it to get the result or if you only want to append to it if the postDate is less than the existing postDate for a given user?

Comment: Hi Joakim, I think the second approach should be correcter than the first approach, but yes, I want append if ...

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary cannot have duplicate keys and the dictionaries are not based on sorting, they are based on key value. This means you can't order a dictionary.

But, on the other hand, remove a value from a dictonary in swift is easy you only needs to do

```
dic.removeValue(forKey: "user2")
```

With conditional

```
var hues = ["Heliotrope": 296, "Coral": 16, "Aquamarine": 156]
if let value = hues.removeValue(forKey: "Coral") {
    print("The value \(value) was removed.")
}
// Prints "The value 16 was removed."
```

Answer (score -1):

it's this simple,

```
if v < comments["john"] { comments["john'] = v }
```